# Rails 4 xeditable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, x-editable

I've been using Xeditable (gem bootstrap-editable-rails) in Rails 3 with great success.

I just started a Rails 4 app, and Xeditable isn't working.  It doesn't display the choices. The drop down contains blank lines.

In Rails 3, I'm using RABL for json.  Rails 4 has jbuilder.

Site model:

```
  belongs_to :type
```

This is the view code:

```
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="xeditable" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-resource="site" data-source="/types" data-name="type_id" data-url="/sites/<%= site.id %> " data-original-title="Select Type">
        <%= site.type.typecode %>
      </a>
    </td>
```

If I use this as the URL localhost:3000/types.json, I get back the correct json list.

This is the screen (when you click the selection, you get a list of blanks).

[image]

Comment: We need more info: does your app sends an AJAX request to the server in order to get the types in JSON everytime you hit the Type value? Does your browser show you an HTTP error in this process? How did you implement / initialize the x-editable field(s)?

Comment: Xeditable uses AJAX to get the JSON values from the types table.  The browser does not show an error.

Comment: You have an extra space in the `data-url` HTML property (at the end), can it be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I removed the space - still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I had to change the jbuilder index file:

```
json.array!(@types) do |type|
  json.text type.typecode
  json.value type.id
end
```